# Working with delegate in swift

Tags: swift, delegates

Im trying to figure out how to work with delegates and protocols.

I have a MessageFetcher class which fetches messages from a url.

```
class MessageFetcher {
 func getCurrentMessagesFromString(urlStringL: String) {..}
}
```

I created a protocol

```
protocol MessageFetcherDelegate {
 func currentMessagesDidUpdate()
}
```

I have a View controller which displays the messages and conforms to the MessageFetcherDelegate protocol:

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, MessageFetcherDelegate {

 var messageFetcher = MessageFetcher()
 var delegate: MessageFetcherDelegate?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  delegate = self
 }

 func currentMessagesDidUpdate() {
  collectionView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

I want the view controller to be notified when the fetcher has updated the messages array and reload the collection views data.

Where am I going wrong and what do I need to add? How do I notify the controller that messages have been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class `MessageFetcher` you need to add delegate property not in `MessagesViewController`:

```
class MessageFetcher {
  func getCurrentMessagesFromString(urlStringL: String) {..}
  var delegate: MessageFetcherDelegate?
}
```

And your `MessagesViewController` should looks like below, see comments for explanation:

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, MessageFetcherDelegate {

 var messageFetcher = MessageFetcher()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  // Declare MessagesViewController class as a deleagte od message Fetcher
  messageFetcher.delegate = self
 }

 func currentMessagesDidUpdate() {
  collectionView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

Now what left to do is call delegate method inside `MessageFetcher`, add this code when the fetcher has updated the messages:

```
delegate?.currentMessagesDidUpdate()
```